# Issue with Running .NET 6 in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, .net-6.0

I installed .NET 6 to be able to use with Visual studio 2019 but cannot see version 6 inside the visual studio

need support

Answer (score 0):

> .NET 6 is supported with Visual Studio 2022 and Visual Studio 2022 for Mac. **It is not supported with Visual Studio 2019**, Visual Studio for Mac 8, or MSBuild 16. If you want to use .NET 6, you will need to upgrade to Visual Studio 2022 (which is also now 64-bit). .NET 6 is supported with the Visual Studio Code C# extension.

This is from the Dev blog here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-6/

Also there is a thread here - [Visual Studio 2019 Not Showing .NET 6 Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69773547/visual-studio-2019-not-showing-net-6-framework).

Answer (score -1):

Of course, SSIS still does not work with Visual Studio 2022.  And this is holding up a lot of upgrades from Visual Studio 2019.