# Visual Studio Community edition vs .NET 7.0

Tags: .net, vs-community-edition

I installed the .NET 7.0 SDK. and Runtime.
I Checked id with dotnet --info, I saw what I expected.
I installed VS Community version, began to create a new console application for multi platform, but I just saw the .NET version 6.0 in the drop down list.
Why didn't see the (already installed) .NET version 7.0?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The version of VS you installed is not a subtle detail.  But it is probably an old one that does not yet support .net7, you would not have to install .net7 separately if you have a recent one.  VS2022, version 17.4.0 or higher required.

Comment: Check out the installed version- see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74443175/2501279) answer.

Comment: enter to "Visual Studio Installer" > Installed > Visual Studio Community 2022 > Modify > Individual components > then mark ".NET 7.0" and klick Modify